# Facebook like button returns incorrect query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Hi guys I've searched through the questions and haven't been able to find an answer for this. I've hit a dead end and my companies analytics team is starting to worry about the tracking data they collect.

We currently use sitecatalysts campaign codes for tracking and collecting data on the website. There are a very small footprint query params that are randomly placed on links throughout the site.

For example: `?cmp=23-42`

The query is attached correctly to the share button and from what I can tell is being passed on form submission. From inspecting the iframe on the page, I see the following value in a hidden form field.

```
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="href" value="http://my-site.com/some-post-or-article-name?cmp=23-42">
```

Headers sent after postings. Using chrome dev tools.

```
fb_dtsg:AQCabg9S
href:http://my-site.com/some-post-or-article-name?cmp=23-42
ref:
nobootload:
action:like
comment_text:test posts
comment:test posts
__user:181...
__a:1
__dyn:7w
__req:7
phstamp:165816797981035783273
```

After I post the like and whatever comments I want, I open facebook and click on the link I just posted. I get my unique tracking query replaced by facebook query params.

`http://my-site.com/some-post-or-article-name?fb_action_ids=4184...&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=2883...`

This happens for every article and event that we have listed which is currently somewhere in the 60k range, and this is where my issue lies. So my questions are...

Is there something that is mentioned in the facebook docs that I'm missing, such as adding an  attribute to my fbml tag that looks like `query="cmp=23-42&more_stuff=more-custom-stuff"`? So that when added my unique query params can be automatically appended to the end of the facebook query params.

Has anyone experienced this issue, how did you solve it?

Are there any creative, but non-hacky ways of associating the returned fb_action_ids or fb_aggregation_id with custom campaign codes, if I can't use custom tracking?

Is there a workaround?

More information about our web app I can share.
Platform: RoR (I'm open to using a gem that solves this problem, if there are any available)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get rid of facebook shared/liked URL query (via mod\_rewrite)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12081298/get-rid-of-facebook-shared-liked-url-query-via-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Are servers are nginx and phusion passenger not apache, we don't have access to mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` option allows for users to append custom data to the returned query string located in the `fb_ref` param.

Found here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Unfortunately for sight catalysts tags this isn't very helpful since the script that handles data reporting automatically looks for campaign codes in the url through an onload method. Here is a bit of useful js I wrote for extracting the values from the `fb_ref` param. Fill free to modify this as needed.

```
facebookCustomQueryString: function(){
 if( window.location.href.indexOf( 'fb_ref=' ) == -1 ) return;
 var location = window.location.href,
     params = location.split('?').pop().split('&'),
     refCode, iframe, container;

 for(var i=0, m=params.length; i<m; i++){
  if( params[i].indexOf('fb_ref') > -1 ){
    var ref = params[i];
    refCode = ref.replace('fb_ref=','');
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

Explained::

1. The first conditions returns out of the function if the `fb_ref=` isn't in the url
2. Next setup a few local variables (I didn't want to keep writing window.location so I grabbed that too)
3. Loop over the params array, find my match and remove the [key]. Store the value into the refCode variable.

That's all you need for getting your values back. I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but this script is running before jQuery loads.

If your in my position and still need to trigger tracking for the site catalysts code or whatever it is your using, add the following to the above method. This will create an iframe on the page and set its source to the base url plus whatever custom query you originally needed returned.

```
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('class',''); // I added absolute positioning -9999px left/top .01em height/width
iframe.setAttribute('id',''+Math.random()); // any random id name here optional for some browsers
iframe.setAttribute('src',location.split('?').shift()+'?'+refCode);
iframe.setAttribute('onload', 'foo.remove(this)' ); // added the onload function to remove the iframe, reporting should be done by this time. Make sure your method foo.remove() is accessible in the DOM 

container = document.createElement('div'); // create a container to hold the iframe, optional, depends on your site markup
container.setAttribute('id',''+Math.random()); // another random id
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(container); // add the container to the body
container.appendChild(iframe); // add the iframe to the container
```

Lastly, my remove method.. Once again fill free to modify this as needed.

```
remove: function(ui){
 ui.parentNode.innerHTML = '';
 ui.remove(ui.selectedIndex);
}
```

For IE browsers you might need to modify the remove method a bit. I haven't tested these yet, but you can try

```
remove: function(ui){
 ui.parentElement.removeChild(ui);
  // or
 var parent = ui.parentElement;
 parent.removeNode(true);
}
```

I hope this was helpful for anyone in my situation...